# Veda Mantra related to 2 people talking privately without realizing god is listening

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, shloka, reference-request

There was a Vedic mantra that I came recently across in a book, but apparently, I can't recall the exact mantra. I do remember its meaning, though; it was something like:

> When two people are talking privately thinking no one is listening to their conversation, God is listening to their conversation.

Does anyone know the exact mantra? It may have been from the Rig Veda.

(I tried searching online but couldn't find it; does anyone have suggestions for how to search for it? Reading all the books again would be very tedious...)